# Apache Nifi: Monitor Files in Queue for longer duration

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I have an ETL pipeline setup on Apache Nifi. It has more than 1300 processors. I need to get into each process group manually to check whether there are any files stuck in a queue. Is there any way that these queues can be monitored and notified automatically?

Comment: There is a summary page where you could see all the processors, quee, etc: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Summary_Page

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm looking for an automated solution that triggers an email / notification for the above scenario